# Getting correct height of an app part after removing item from repeat

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, resize, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building an app part in sharepoint (o365) using angularjs, which displays a list of items i'm following (docs, sites). I display the items as tiles (in rows of 4 below each other), and to fit the app part nicely on any page, I calculate the height of the most outer div (topContainer) which contains all items). I calculate the height when the ng-repeat finishes rendering (with a custom directive). The resizing is done with a postmessage:

```
var resizeAppPart = function (width, height) { 
    if (senderId && hostweburl) {
        var message = "<Message senderId=" + senderId + " >"
                + "resize(" + width + "," + height + ")</Message>";
        window.parent.postMessage(message, hostweburl);
    }
}
```

The height and width are provided by

```
 var heightDoc = $("#topContainer").height();
 var widthDoc = $("#topContainer").width();
 myUtils.resizeAppPart(widthDoc, heightDoc);
```

If I use

```
$(document).height/width();
```

it delivers the same result.

This works perfectly when loading the page.
However I also provide a button which allows a user to 'unfollow' any of the displayed items. Then the item disappears (splice from the array, the repeat gets updated nicely), and I try to recalculate the height of the app part (so no gap remains when unfollowing an item). I can successfully call the recalculate size function for the app part (that's not the problem) however I just can't get the right height of the app part.. The height remains the same as before unfollowing an item, even though there's now a gap where the unfollowed item was..

So I'm trying to find a method to get the right height of the app part after removing the item from the array. Any Ideas?

Comment: Try `$timeout`, which `$apply`s after all digestion is done.

Comment: Doens't work, still gives the height as if the removed item is still there. When removing another item, it gives the hight it should have given when removing the previous item